# How do i notify a user whenever his or her post is liked by another user in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm looking for a way to notify users whenever his/her post is liked by another user on my Ruby on Rails app. I'm using Acts As Votable.

Comment: Shouldn't it just be a simple call like `UserMailer.with(@post).post_liked.deliever_now`? What have you done so far? What specific problem do you face?

Comment: I don't have the idea of setting this up after i implemented the like feature, that's why i'm asking.

Comment: You have to provide at least some code and show us what you have done so far.

Comment: I consider reading about [Acion Mailer Basics](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html) in the Rails Guides.

Answer (score 0):

There are at least three ways to solve this problem.

1. [AJAX request](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html) that sends an email using [Action Mailer](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html)
2. synchronous request but I wouldn't recommend it as after clicking "Like" button the user would experience a full page reload.
3. If you don't want AJAX you can use a built-in rails [ActiveJob](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html) to move the request to the background. It provides lots of options like delaying the job for later or executing it now. The job woyld simply send an email using [Action Mailer](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html). This is a solution I would probably go for myself.